# Slider which supports Video + Images

Tags: jquery, html, video, slider

I am looking to find a slider which supports both images and videos, as the same gallery would have both. I would like that the slider would ideally loop through the images, but when it comes to the video, it would calculate the length of the video before looping through the next image.

This will need to also be editable, ideally.

What are your recommendations? Is this something which I have to build, or is there ready made jQuery Sliders which support this?

Comment: How did you manage in the end ? I want same functionality ..Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Anything slider can do that

http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

Demo

http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

Comment: thanks, however I want something which is unmanaged. Therefore the video should play on its turn, and when it is finished, the rotation resumes.  This will go on a TV in a store, thus, this is something automated.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use this as a base and add to it. 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/

Comment: Did you manage to get it support videos and photos? Is it something you can manually do, or is it editable and the client can do it himself?

Comment: I haven't used videos, but they should work, you would have to do the work to add them yourself, or make an interface for your client to add them .

Comment: I prefer having something which already works, so it would not consume so much of my time